# Scroll to the bottom of a web page

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to make a little script which takes a look at main page of web and finds adds.

The problem is that there are web pages which contains infinite scroll. If this code was built for particular web page, I could use locating elements and scrolling.

But I can't figure out how to make Selenium to scroll at the very bottom of any page?

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, something);")
```

PS: If there is very huge page, break it down after several seconds of scrolling.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Doesn't `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` work?

Comment: @hellpanderrr If I just put this after driver.get(url), no, it does not work. Probably because it scrolls only a bit of the page, not to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method that i used for Java, get the window size and then scroll to that position using javascript. Here's how to do it in Java (hope you can implement the concept in python too) -

```
double pageHeight = testBase.TestBase.driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+pageHeight+")");
```

If you are implementing an infinite scroll then you can put the `executeScript()` lines in a loop. Hope it helps.